# Reverse polarity protection for LiPo

Tags: batteries, datasheet, lithium-ion

I'm looking at using the [S-8261](http://datasheet.sii-ic.com/en/battery_protection/S8261_E.pdf) for reverse polarity protection. On page 24, it reads

> R2.. Select a resistance as large as possible to prevent large current
>   when a charger is connected in reverse.*5

Yet, *5 reads

> If R2 has a resistance higher than 4 kΩ, the charging current may not be cut when a high-voltage charger is connected.

So does that mean R2 shouldn't be "as large as possible" but rather <= 4kOhms?

In fact, is R2 designed to protect against reverse polarity protection even if it's embedded in a device that drains the battery rather than one charging the battery? The language it uses seems to have an emphasis on 'charger'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because R2 is connected to the charger side of the FETs, it is exposed to the full charger voltage. A properly designed Li-ion charger should never put out more than 4.2V anyway - so this shouldn't be a problem unless the wrong charger is used, or its voltage limiter fails and produces an abnormally high output voltage.

The 'possible' in "as large as possible" obviously refers to the largest *permitted* value, not just what is physically possible (which is infinity Ohms or an open circuit - not very useful). I would use the recommended 2kΩ, which limits reverse current to ~2mA at -4.2V.

> is R2 designed to protect against reverse polarity protection even if
>   it's embedded in a device that drains the battery rather than one
>   charging the battery?  The language it uses seems to have an emphasis on
>   'charger'.

Draining the battery won't put a negative voltage on it. The protection circuit handles chargers that are incorrectly connected in reverse (either directly or through a device's charger socket), or installing the battery into a device in reverse (which would probably fry the device before you got a chance to charge through it!).

Comment: I see. So do you mean, if the battery is connected in reverse in a draining device, no protection is actually needed?

Comment: Not against reverse voltage, but it may still need over-current protection (as may the device). Most ICs act like a forward biased diode in reverse, and will draw enough current to destroy themselves (and possibly the battery) if the current is not externally limited.

Comment: Sure. But how come reverse voltage in a draining device doesn't need protection against?

Comment: The S-8261 is a _battery_ protection device. It is _not_ designed to protect a draining device from reverse polarity. Its over-current cutoff may protect the device, but it would be safer for the device to have its own protection circuit (eg. series diode) if the battery can be inserted backwards. Note that The S-8261 _must_ be connected to the cell with correct polarity. Reverse voltage will kill it! Therefore it should not be embedded into a device which has a removable battery that can be inserted backwards. Normally it is hardwired to the cell (in a battery or a device).

Comment: Oh! That's an interesting insight. So I was hoping to use the S-8261 to protect the (potentially unprotected) battery from the device. If reverse voltage kills it, do you know of a more suitable IC/setup? Keep the S-8261 but only through a series diode?

Comment: To protect the device from reverse battery polarity you could put a diode in series (only if you don't need to charge the battery in the device), or a MOSFET with Source/Drain swapped to prevent its body diode conducting in reverse, or a physical interlock that prevents the battery from being connected in reverse (eg. battery springs shaped to only make contact with the correct end of the cell). You could still embed the S-8261 inside the device to protect the cell from over-charge and over-discharge (the most common causes of Li-ion battery failure).